# SOQL query using LIKE or Contains with IN

Tags: apex, soql

Are there any workarounds for creating a query using the `LIKE` operator on a set of strings? I would like to create a new object(Exclusions) which would house records that have a field for keywords that should be excluded from a query. I would like to have the method query for the exclusion records, and then exclude the cases where the subject matches any of the keywords the query brings back.

The only workaround I can think of would be using a string query, then looping through exclusion results and adding additional `OR` clauses with a single `LIKE` operator for each exclusion record. I feel like there may be SOQL limits I may run into here (string length of query depending on how many exclusion records)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can use `LIKE` with `IN`

This is how you can do it with `Set<String>`

```
Set<string> setNames= Set<string>();
setNames.add('sample%');
setNames.add('testaccount%');
List<Accounts> lstAccounts = [select id, name from Account where name like :setNames];
```